# Quick Build impossible in TeXmaker : pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Tags: latex, miktex, texmaker

I (try to) make my first steps with LaTeX in order to write my internship's report. I thus downloaded TeXmaker and MikTeX and tried to compile my first document.

However, when I try to click on "Run" after having selected "Quick Bild", I got the following error message: "Error : could not start the command : pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "test".tex"

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1o73h.png)

I browsed the web in search of a solution but could not find something relevant to my case. Indeed, some forums suggest that the problem is due to the fact that the user did not install a compiler. However, as said above I successfully installed MikTeX, so I do not understand...

I tried to uninstall both TeXmaker several times, but it did not solve the problem.

I also tried to uninstall MikTeX, but it does not seem totally possible. Indeed, when I want to finish the setup and select the first option (Finish private setup), I get an error message: "The requested package is unknown."

[MikteX problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgwjU.png)

When I select the second option (Restart as administrator...), I get the following error message: "Administrator mode startup refused because this is not a shared MiKTeX setup."

Could you please help me? I have no clue about what I am supposed to do...

Cheers!

Laura

Comment: open cmd and type `pdflatex`. If that command cannot be found, add the miktex bin folder to PATH.

Comment: I tried to write pdflatex in cmd, but I get the following message "pdflatex" is not recognised as an intern or extern command, an executable software or a command file".

I would thus like to add the miktex bin folder to PATH, but I do not know how to proceed (sorry for the probably stupid question, but as said above I just begin with LaTeX...

Comment: This is more a windows question. There are lots of tutorials out there, [this for example](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/).